# How to send attribute values in invoice mail in magento-1.9.1.1

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, invoice, magento-1.9.1.1

I have developed one website on **magento-1.9.1.1**. I need to add the **weight** attribute values along with order information in invoice email.

Comment: pls check, hope it will help you : https://www.sonassi.com/blog/magento-kb/display-attributes-on-invoice-or-packing-slip-in-magento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply add information here.

```
app/design/frontend/[package name]/[your theme]/template/email/order/items/invoice/default.phtml
```

You can get the product item weight like this:

```
<?php echo $_item->getOrderItem()->getWeight(); ?>
```

Comment: I want to add weight in invoice

Comment: @you can get item product weight.  `echo $_item->getProduct()->getWeight();`

Comment: Hi sir.  i added the following  <?php $_orderItem = $_item->getOrderItem(); ?>  and after the get name i added this.  <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_orderItem->getWeight() ) ?>  but i didnt receive the weight of product in invoice mail

Comment: use this code `echo $_item->getProduct()->getWeight();`

Comment: i added <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getProduct()->getWeight();) ?>  now i got Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /app/design/frontend/smartwave/porto/template/email/order/items/invoice/default.phtml on line 33

Comment: error was in ur code try this `<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getProduct()->getWeight()); ?>`

Comment: i updated . now i got another sir . Fatal error: Call to a member function getWeight() on a non-object in /app/design/frontend/smartwave/porto/template/email/order/items/invoice/default.phtml on line 33

Comment: try `<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getWeight()); ?>`

Answer (score 2):

Magento,does not save weight of item  at Sales invoice model.You did not find any field at  **`sales_flat_invoice_item`** table.

Magento save an order item weight at sales items table, so you need to call `Mage_Sales_Order_Item` Object of that sales invoice ite,

```
$orderItem = $_item->getOrderItem();
$orderItem->getWeight(); // get weight
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Amit. where and what i should add this? i mean the path. i am using smartwave package with porto theme.

Comment: path should be `app/design/frontend/[Your_Package]/[Your_template]/template/email/order/items/invoice/default.phtml`

Comment: Hi Amit, i added the following  <?php $_orderItem = $_item->getOrderItem(); ?>  and after the get name i added this.  <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_orderItem->getWeight() ) ?>  but i didnt receive the weight of product in invoice mail