# Get long-description in magento template

Tags: magento-1.9, php

### How to fetch **long description** in template.

I have want to fetch the long descritpion of Product

and show it in **Template** file list.phtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to enable **description** attribute for **use in product listing** from Manage Attribute section.

Then add

```
<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getDescription() , 'description'); ?>
```

after

```
 <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name'); ?>
```

Comment: Hi Amit. please find this. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141742/how-to-send-attribute-values-in-invoice-mail-in-magento-1-9-1-1/141766?noredirect=1#comment192088_141766

Comment: ok,i will   look this question

Comment: After look on that please post answer or comment plz

Comment: Please check the answer

Answer (score 0):

go to `catalog->Attribute`  search your attribute `description` and set `use in product listing`  to yes.

and

write Below code if you have single language store or description is same for all store

```
echo $_product->getDescription();
```

Otherwise for fetching language wise short description you can use below code

```
<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getDescription() , 'description'); ?>
```

Comment: Hello murtuza, please find this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141742/how-to-send-attribute-values-in-invoice-mail-in-magento-1-9-1-1/141766?noredirect=1#comment192088_141766